# Query configuring IE to use a proxy server

Tags: website, internet-explorer, proxy, administrator, privacy

If I configure internet explorer to use a proxy server,

- Will the websites I surf be hidden from the system administrator of my lan?
- Will my IP be hidden from the website administrators of the browsing website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on several factors:

- DNS lookups will probably still travel across the LAN, and could be watched/logged.
- If you are connecting to a proxy over HTTP (you probably are) - that connection will be unencrypted and easily sniffed for the sufficiently motivated sysadmin.
- The IP that the web site admin will see most likely will be whatever the address is of the outside proxy server (in theory, your proxy could be chained to another, etc.).

Comment: i couldnt the get the third point ..whether web admin can find my computer ip?

Comment: Yours? No. Somebody's? Yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your sys admin might not see the IP of the specific website, but they will see the IP of the proxy. If they feel motivated, they can look that up and see you are using a proxy. Which, if the desire is to keep your online activities hidden, will still land you in a possible meeting w/ the admin about why you are using a proxy to browse the internet.